# Conversion from OpenEXR Image File (Spherical Panoramic DepthMap) Causing a Geomerty Transformation to Fail

Tags: c#, c++, transformation, computational-geometry

I am reading a TiledExr file as follows using C++ and [OpenEXR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenEXR)

```
std::vector<double> TiledExrDepthMapExtractor::extractDepthMap(const char* filePath,
    int& width, int& height, ProgressFunc& progressCallback, ErrorFunc& errorCallback)
{
    // Do some stuff then...
    return pixelVector;
}
```

This gets called from C#

```
public class ExrDepthMapExtractor : IDepthMapExtractor
{
    public RawDepthMap GetDepthMap(string filePath)
    {
        return ExtractRawDepthMap(filePath, Callbacks.ProgressCallback, Callbacks.ErrorCallback);
    }

    private unsafe RawDepthMap ExtractRawDepthMap(string filePath,
        Callbacks.ProgressFunc progressCallback, Callbacks.ErrorFunc errorCallback)
    {
        using (InternalExtractRawDepthMapWrapper(filePath, out RawDepthMap rdm, progressCallback, errorCallback))
        {
            rdm.Source = filePath;
            return rdm;
        }
    }

    private unsafe PixelVectorSafeHandle InternalExtractRawDepthMapWrapper(
        string filePath, out RawDepthMap rdm, Callbacks.ProgressFunc progressCallback, Callbacks.ErrorFunc errorCallback)
    {
        if (!NativeMethods.ExtractDepthMapAs1DArray(out PixelVectorSafeHandle pixelVectorHandle,
            out double* pixels, out int width, out int height, filePath, progressCallback))
            throw new FormatException($"Depth map could not be extracted from \"{filePath}\"");

        var pixelList = new List<double>();
        for (int i = 0; i < width * height; i++)
            pixelList.Add(pixels[i]);

        rdm = new RawDepthMap()
        {
            Source = filePath,
            DepthMapArray = pixelList,
            Height = height,
            Width = width
        };

        return pixelVectorHandle;
    }
}
```

Via an API

```
[SuppressUnmanagedCodeSecurity()]
internal static class NativeMethods
{
    [DllImport("Blundergat.OpenExr.Adapter.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
    [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.I1)]
    internal static unsafe extern bool ExtractDepthMapAs1DArray(
        out PixelVectorSafeHandle vectorHandle,
        out double* points,
        out int width,
        out int height,
        string filePath,
        Callbacks.ProgressFunc progressCallback);

    [DllImport("Blundergat.OpenExr.Adapter.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
    internal static unsafe extern bool Release(IntPtr itemsHandle);
}
```

and converted to a `RawDepthMap`

```
public class RawDepthMap
{
    public string Source { get; set; }

    public List<double> DepthMapArray { get; set; }

    public int Height { get; set; }

    public int Width { get; set; }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        string source = !String.IsNullOrEmpty(Source) ? Source : "N/A";
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder($"RawDepthMap: Source \"{source}\"");
        if (DepthMapArray != null)
            builder.Append($", Array size {DepthMapArray:N0}");

        builder.Append($", Width {Width:N0}, Height {Height:N0}");
        return builder.ToString();
    }
}
```

This is a spherical depth map (it is a spherical panorama image), essentially an 1D array of depth mesurements. From this, I convert to a Cartesian PointCloud using

```
public class DepthMapToPointCloudAdapter : IDepthMapToPointCloudAdapter
{
    public DepthMapToPointCloudAdapter() { }

    public IPointCloud GetPointCloudFromDepthMap(RawDepthMap rdm)
    {
        // Do some transformations. 
        return new PointCloud(dataPoints.ToArray(), rdm.Source);
    }
}
```

This give the following point cloud

[image]

Now, I need to read an image EXR file. I do this again like above using C++

```
std::vector<double> ImageExrDepthMapExtractor::extractDepthMap(const char* filePath,
    int& width, int& height, ProgressFunc& progressCallback, ErrorFunc& errorCallback)
{
    // Do some reading... 
    return pixelVector;
}
```

Same conversion routine to Cartesian `PointCloud` but this time I get a spherical geometry.

[image]

This is clearly down to the way I am reading the image (RGBA) .exr file, but what exactly is causing this?

Comment: I am not familiar with EXR files, but I have been manipulating quite a bit of geospatial data with [Generic Mapping Tools](https://github.com/GenericMappingTools/gmt). Whenever I experienced something like what you describe, it was usually a projection issue. Could that also be the case here? See also: https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/89585/how-are-360-photos-stored-and-processed